# How to execute a string in SQL Server and stored its result into a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetEmployeeSal]
    @Mode           varchar(50) = '',
    @IsMultiple     bit = 0,        
    @EmployeeMstID  bigint = 0,
    @EmployeeMstIDs varchar(MAX) = '',
    @Message        varchar(100) = ''
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    BEGIN TRY

    IF (@Mode = 'GetEmployeeSal')
    BEGIN
        IF(@IsMultiple = 0)
        BEGIN       
            SELECT @CurrentSal = COUNT(1) 
            FROM EmployeeMst
            WHERE EmployeeMstID = @EmployeeMstID AND IsFinancialYear = 1

            SELECT @PreviousSal = COUNT(1) 
            FROM EmployeeMst
            WHERE EmployeeMstID = @EmployeeMstID

            IF (@CurrentSal = @PreviousSal)
            BEGIN
                SET @Message = 'No Salary Revision has been performed'
            END
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            EXEC ('SELECT @CurrentSal = COUNT(1) 
                   FROM EmployeeMst
                   WHERE EmployeeMstID IN (' + @EmployeeMstIDs + ') 
                     AND IsFinancialYear = 1')

            EXEC ('SELECT @PreviousSal = COUNT(1) 
                   FROM EmployeeMst
                   WHERE EmployeeMstID IN '( + @EmployeeMstIDs + )'')

            IF(@CurrentSal = @PreviousSal)
            BEGIN
                  SET @Message = 'No Salary Revision has been performed'
            END
        END
    END

    IF(@@ERROR = 0)
    BEGIN
        COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END 
    ELSE
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION    
    END TRY     
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END CATCH
END
```

Comment: I am facing the problem with the else part. The EXEC command leads me to the try catch block and the without throwing any error it just rollback the complete entire transaction. Please help me out to find a better solution

Comment: looks like SQL Server, please always tag with the database you are using, "sql" is a standards based language not a database type. & What version are you running?

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1) with express edition

Comment: do you have access to the function `STRING_SPLIT()` in that version? if so you could probably avoid using dynamic sql completely.

Comment: No I don't have access to such function.

Comment: probably because of "compatibility level" see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql

Comment: The level of Database compatibility is 100 and I my team does not insist to change as other module would get disturbed and the STRING_SPLIT is available with higher compatible version having more than or equal to 130

Comment: ok. just info. that's all. u could build your own split string function instead there are 1,000's available to choose from. just a thought. all up to you. no need to reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is: `@CurrentSal` variable is not in the context of your `EXEC` statement.

> How to execute a string in SQL Server and stored its result into a
>   variable

You can use `sp_executequery` and `output` like this

```
DECLARE @CurrentSal INT

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = 'select @CurrentSal = 2'

--EXEC @sql

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@CurrentSal nvarchar(20) OUTPUT', @CurrentSal OUTPUT 

SELECT @CurrentSal
```

Demo link: http://rextester.com/IHBP16111

Comment: Thank You @TriV for the valuable time spent to solve the problem